# PHP + Smarty + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Help me please! How to transfer data from table to smarty?

Function:

```
public function getBanLog() {
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `bans`") or die($mysqli->error);
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
}
```

index.php:

```
$user = new UserInfo();
$smarty = new Smarty();

$smarty->assign("userInfo", $user);
$smarty->assign('ban', $user->getBanLog());
$smarty->display('template/ban.tpl');
```

ban.tpl:

```
{foreach from=$ban item=row}
    <td>{$row.id}</td>
    <td>{$row.banned}</td>
    <td>{$row.admin}</td>
    <td>{$row.reason}</td>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: code looks fine whats the problem ?

Comment: Only thing suspect here is the lack of a `WHERE` clause in your query, which appears to return all bans for all users, not just the user as implied by the `UserInfo()`.

Comment: @dianuj `getBanLog()` returns nothing, and `$result = $query = $mysqli->query`

Answer (score 4):

Your `getBanLog()` function returns nothing, need to add a return statement. Also `$result = $query = $mysqli->..` is not correct.

Try this

```
public function getBanLog() {
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `bans`") or die($mysqli->error);
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```